# How to extract CDATA content with TWIG using Perl

Tags: xml, perl, parsing, cdata, xml-twig

I am new to Perl, so I have little experience using it, and I have to extract the content inside CDATA using TWIG and Perl from the following xml file:

```
    <?xml version='1.0'  encoding="utf-8"?>
    <text>
    <![CDATA[
    1. Democracia ukata Estado de Derecho sutinchata kamachinaka ch’amanchañataki

    ...
    ]]>
    </text>
```

Sorry if this question is repeated somewhere.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `twig_handlers` to do filtering using `#CDATA` as xpath expression.

Content of `script.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new( 
    twig_handlers => {
        '#CDATA' => sub { print $_->text },
    },  
)->parsefile( shift );
```

Run it like:

```
perl script.pl xmlfile
```

That yields:

```
1. Democracia ukata Estado de Derecho sutinchata kamachinaka ch’amanchañataki

...
```